# Does the torus cover the punctured disc?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I am working through Massey's introduction to algebraic topology,
https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387902715
and I have come to the section on covering spaces where it mentions that every induced homomorphism from the fundamental group of a covering space to the fundamental group of the space covered is injective (Chapter 5, section 4, theorem 4.1)

My question is then, does the torus cover a punctured disc, and if so, is the induced homomorphism injective? The torus' fundamental group is clearly larger than that of the punctured disc and so I can't reconcile this with theorem 4.1. I can only then assume that the torus doesn't actually cover the punctured disc but I can't see how that is so.

Any help with where I have gone wrong in my thinking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you wrote is a proof that there is no such a covering map: The group $Z^2$ does not embed in $Z$ as a subgroup.

Comment: The torus is compact and a covering map is required to be surjective. This implies that the punctured disk should be compact aswell. This is because the image of a compact space under a continuous function is also compact. This is clearly not true. It's not a proof in line with homotopy theory but a proof nonetheless.

Comment: @Lundström That makes a lot of sense, but what if we were to replace the punctured disc in this scenario with a closed annulus? If im not mistaken a closed annulus is compact and would therefore fix the issue of compact space mapping to non-compact.

Comment: But a closed annulus is a manifold with boundary, thus if we had a covering map (which is local homeomorphism), then also the torus must have a boundary which is not true.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So ultimately then, no the torus doesnt cover the punctured disc or annulus on account of the cocering maps not preserving the necessary conditions. I will mark the question as resolved. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: @PhilKSebben Then you should answer your own question and accept the answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost Okay, I wasnt sure if doing that was alright or not. I was hoping I could mark a comment as the answer but I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not.
As pointed out in the comments to my question, the covering map between a space and it's covering space has to be a continuous map, which must therefore preserve the compactness of the space. Since a torus is compact and a punctured disc is not, the covering map doesn't preserve compactness and is therefore not a continuous map.

Thank you to the commenters for pointing this out.